# How can i add buttons/textBoxes with events to an Excel form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, dynamically-generated

I am trying to programatically generate a Help form that among other things, has a list of Hyperlinks that the user can click to access them.

This is the code I am using so far. Generating the buttons manually is not possible, as they are way to many, i only kept 3 in this example (this code will create 3 buttons, but only the last one has the event attached to it, how can i generate new events for each new button?):

```
'form z_test - empty form with only code in the background

Option Explicit

Public tbPin As MSForms.textBox         ' The textbox control.
Dim objMyEventClass As New C_events       ' Create an object of the Class (where we declared the events).

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim arrHyperlinks, Hi, topI
    
    arrHyperlinks = Array("google.com", "bing.com", "facebook.com")
    topI = 30
    
    For Each Hi In arrHyperlinks
        Dim btEx As MSForms.CommandButton
        Set btEx = Me.Controls.add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        With btEx
            .TOP = topI
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 130
            .Height = 25
            .Caption = Hi
        End With
        topI = topI + 30
        Set objMyEventClass.btEvents = btEx         ' Attach at event to the button.
    Next
End Sub

'class c_events
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents tbEvents As MSForms.textBox
Public WithEvents btEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub btEvents_click()
   MsgBox btEvents.Caption
End Sub
```

Kind regards,
Daniel

Comment: You did not supply the code you are using, but I am assuming you are just copying the code again, top and left would have to change, height and width would stay the same. Experiment with that.

Comment: Davesexcel I allso put together a simplified example, as the original code is way to complicated to display here. If you just copy paste the code into a class and an empty form, and just run the form, you will get 3 buttons, but only the last one is bound to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only has one class which contains 1 button and you keep overlaying the button inside the loop. So only the last button is hooked to an event. One approach to solve this is to have a collection of C_events classes.  Here is you original code slightly modified to implement this idea:

```
Option Explicit

Public tbPin As MSForms.TextBox         ' The textbox control.
Private ButtonEvents As Collection
Private objMyEventClass As C_events       ' Create an object of the Class (where we declared the events).

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim arrHyperlinks, Hi, topI
    
    arrHyperlinks = Array("google.com", "bing.com", "facebook.com")
    topI = 30
    Set ButtonEvents = New Collection
    
    For Each Hi In arrHyperlinks
        Set objMyEventClass = New C_events
        Dim btEx As MSForms.CommandButton
        Set btEx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        With btEx
            .Top = topI
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 130
            .Height = 25
            .Caption = Hi
        End With
        topI = topI + 30
        Set objMyEventClass.btEvents = btEx         ' Attach at event to the button.
        ButtonEvents.Add objMyEventClass
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you are amazing, thank you very much! Do you have any advice or tutorials i should follow on how to help me better understand classes ?

Comment: Nothing specific.  But the web has plenty of [articles and tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+classes&rlz=1C1EODB_enUS703US703&oq=vba&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59l2j0j69i60l3.1119j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).